# Python :raise error_perm, resp ftplib.error_perm: 500?

Tags: python, ftplib

i'm trying to Copy my file from c:\test to my FTP folder ; This is my code :

```
import ftplib
import socket
Name = socket.gethostname()
filename = Name +".csv"
ftp = ftplib.FTP('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
ftp.login('xxxxxx','xxxxxxxx')
ftp.cwd('test')
filematch = "C:\\test\\" + Name + ".csv"
filetocopy = open(filematch,'r')
ftp.storlines('STOR' +filename , filetocopy)
```

but i'm running into an Error :

```
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 500 ?
```

Comment: Check that your user has permission to _write_ to the `test` directory on the FTP server.

Comment: i do have the w permission on that folder

Comment: Solved : Space after 'STOR was missing ... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
import ftplib
import socket
Name = socket.gethostname()
filename = Name +".csv"
ftp = ftplib.FTP('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
ftp.login('xxxxxx','xxxxxxxx')
ftp.cwd('test')
filematch = "C:\\test\\" + Name + ".csv"
filetocopy = open(filematch,'r')
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + filename, filetocopy)
```

Comment: Why is 'STOR  ' needed?