# error_perm_500 using ftplib in Python

Tags: python, ftplib

Within my Python script I am using ftplib. However, I am encountering the `error_perm: 500 ?` error upon performing the below operation:

```
filename = '31379-den-katastrofy-2-konec-sveta-film-2005.html'
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftpupload.net')
ftp.login('onavt_24441681', 'rte22133') 
ftp.cwd('htdocs')
print(ftp.pwd())
print(os.getcwd())
uploadfile = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/path/31379-den-katastrofy-2-konec-sveta- 
film-2005.html', 'rb')
ftp.storlines('STOR' + filename, uploadfile)
```

I can't seem to figure how what is wrong. Any pointers on what should I adjust to get rid of the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python :raise error\_perm, resp ftplib.error\_perm: 500?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261278/python-raise-error-perm-resp-ftplib-error-perm-500)

Comment: Pleas add the entire stack trace, it makes it easier to help. and dont post your password here

Comment: This is not real password. It is just random simbols

Comment: @AurItar, storlines() requires a string-command as first parameter, whose syntax should be `STOR filename`. You can check from my answer below. Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the space after the **STOR** command.

Update the last line with:

```
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + filename, uploadfile)
```

And it should work